# Strange Compilation Error Involving Casting

Tags: java, compiler-errors

I noticed something rather strange when working in my IDE.

```
double x1 = 0, x2 = 0;
int a = (int) x1 = (int) x2;
```

So this is invalid syntax, unsurprisingly. However, it's the explanation of *why* it's invalid syntax that confuses me. When I put this code in Eclipse Luna and hover over the second line, a message appears that says:

> Type mismatch: cannot convert from boolean to int
>
> 1 quick fix available:
>
> Change type of 'a' to 'boolean'

If I ignore the error and proceed to run anyway, even the Throwable stack trace shows the same message:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problems: 
        Type mismatch: cannot convert from boolean to int
        Syntax error on token "=", <= expected
```

I don't understand why the compiler thinks that `(int) x1 = (int) x2` is some sort of comparison that evaluates to `true` or `false`. Does anyone have an idea of why this is so?

Comment: Well, this took some time to be executed by javac and the error is way different: *unexpected type, required: variable found: value*.

Comment: I can see where that's coming from. Do you suppose it's an Eclipse-specific error?

Comment: Yes. When dealing with odd compiler exception erros, try to compile the code with javac first, it will provide a *better* compilation error message.

Comment: @TNT IntelliJ gives the error "variable expected" (with `(int) x1` underlined in red).

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza Thanks. I'll keep that in mind next time.

Answer (score 3):

the castoperator has a higher priority than the assignment operators. due to this, you can't assign the cast value to `x1`, since the compiler actually interprets it as:

```
...
cast x1 to integer
assign (int) x2 to the value of (int) x1
...
```

Step 2 won't work, since `(int) x1` is no `lvalue` (sry for using a term from c++, i have no idea if there even exists a synonym in java).